# Email is sent with no body content via SMTP on Mainframe

Tags: email, smtp, mainframe, jcl

SMTP MIME message has been working fine until couple of weeks. All of sudden body content of the email is blank and shows no data, **Email is being sent but without body content in the email but subject line is apprpriate.** Could someone let me know if it is related to internal support issue or something has been deprecated with SMTP utility. Appreciate your response.

**Technical details follow:** Utility **`IEBGENER`** is used to copy the emailing data to SMTP MIME server. Here is the JCL used:

```
//SENDEMAIL EXEC PGM=IEBGENER                            
//SYSIN    DD DUMMY                                      
//SYSUT1   DD DSN=EMAIL.INPUT.DS,DISP=SHR
//SYSUT2   DD SYSOUT=(B,SMTP)                            
//SYSOUT   DD SYSOUT=*                                  
//SYSPRINT DD SYSOUT=* 
//
```

The EMAIL.INPUT.DS contains

```
HELO IEFSSxx                                            
MAIL FROM:<MYTEST@TESTING.COM>                    
RCPT TO:<YOURTEST@TESTING.COM>                      
DATA                                                    
FROM:     MYTEST@TESTING.COM 
TO:       YOURTEST@TESTING.COM 
SUBJECT:  TEST MESSAGE FROM MVS USING SMTP              
MIME-VERSION: 1.0 
CONTENT-TYPE: TEXT/HTML;BOUNDARY="SIMPLE BOUNDARY"
--SIMPLE BOUNDARY
THIS IS A LINE IN THE BODY OF THE NOTE.                  
--SIMPLE BOUNDARY
.
QUIT
```

Comment: Has been the email server or client updated?

Comment: When I execute what you have posted, I receive... --SIMPLE BOUNDARY THIS IS A LINE IN THE BODY OF THE NOTE. --SIMPLE BOUNDARY ...in my email inbox. All one physical line, just as shown. Since I receive different results than you, perhaps it is a configuration issue. Unfortunately, I do not have access to the configuration files.

Comment: Run the job but change SYSUT2 to be just SYSOUT=*, and inspect the output.

Also, the SYSOUT DD is not used by IEBGENER, and should be removed to eliminate confusion.

Comment: @zarchasmpgmr, I happened to do the same but nothing helped me. Still trying!

Comment: Surprisingly, It has worked till couple of days ago. So it's hard to pick the pit. Still trying, thanks for your time.

Comment: I would now move to the SMTP configuration. Something has probably gotten messed up with the subsystem.

Comment: @zarchasmpgmr, well how do we access configuration files or settings of SMTP so that we may amend the code as needed. Thanks for showing interest! Wish you a nice weekend ahead!!

Comment: It is documented in the Communications Server manuals, TCP/IP. I am too busy to search for it right now.  I set this up in the past but I don't remember exactly where the settings are. I believe you do have to dig around in the USS file structure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect that your SMTP service was upgraded
and may have become more sensitive to errors in setting up messages -- your example has a few...

The `boundary` subparameter of the `Content-type` parameter relates to multipart messages (it is the boundary delimiter between message parts). The `Content-type` of your message is not `multipart` so I imagine that
"support" for the `boundary` subparameter may have been dropped yielding unpredictable results.

You may find it useful to review [RFC 2045](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2045.txt) and [RFC 2046](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2046.txt) which describe
MIME format. The rules for the `boundary` subparameter are defined in RFC2046 under multipart messages.

Proper usage of the boundary delimiter in a multipart message generally requires that
the boundary delimiter be followed by a blank line. Also, the last boundary delimiter, the
one that terminates the last part of the message should have two hyphens appended to it.

Taking all this into consideration, a conforming message would look more like:

```
HELO IEFSSxx                                            
MAIL FROM:<MYTEST@TESTING.COM>                    
RCPT TO:<YOURTEST@TESTING.COM>                      
DATA                                                    
FROM:     MYTEST@TESTING.COM 
TO:       YOURTEST@TESTING.COM 
SUBJECT:  TEST MESSAGE FROM MVS USING SMTP 
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-type: multipart/mixed; boundary="SIMPLE BOUNDARY"

--SIMPLE BOUNDARY

Please open the attachment, to solve your problems...
--SIMPLE BOUNDARY
Content-type: text/html

Try asking <a href="http://www.stackoverflow.com">Stackoverflow</a>
--SIMPLE BOUNDARY--
.
QUIT
```

Note that the blank lines in the above exampe are significant and that the last `boundary` delimiter has two trailing hypens.

Comment: My bad, you're right.  Edited the answer and removed my comment.